# Fine grained password policy with msDS-MaximumPasswordAge set to 2 days asks for reset immediately

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

A fine grained password policy with `msDS-MaximumPasswordAge` set to 2 days asks for reset immediately on Server 2008R2.

After I apply the policy, in the next automatic `gpupdate`, the machine starts asking for new credentials.

Comment: And what is the age of the password?

Comment: The password was changed long before that timespan.

Comment: When you set that policy, you effectively expired the password of any account in scope that had a password age over two days.

Answer (score 6):

As Greg hinted at in his comment, the maximum password age is **always** calculated based on the age of the password in question.

So for example, let's say you have a policy set to 30 days and your password is currently 15 days old.  Everything works normally. Then you change your policy to 2 days. But your password is still 15 days old, so it is immediately considered expired.

Comment: That's what I supposed but couldn´t confirm. Thanks a lot